# How to properly use a global variable in angular config inc. testing

Tags: angularjs, global-variables, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write an angular theme for a wordpress site, and I'm following what seems to be a common wordpress/angular 'pattern' of using `functions.php` to define a global variable that points to the views/partials folder, so that then it can be referenced by the routes.

In `functions.php`:

```
wp_localize_script( 'appJs', 'localized',
    array (
        'partials' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/views'
    )
);
```

And my angular config class:

```
function AngularConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: localized.partials + '/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/projects/', {
            templateUrl: localized.partials + '/projects.html',
            controller: 'ProjectsController'
        })
        .when('/contact/', {
            templateUrl: localized.partials + '/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}

export default AngularConfig;
```

At runtime this works because `localized` is a global, with a property of `partials`. However, my tests (karma, jasmine, phantomjs) fail because the global has not been defined in it's environment. (Also, referencing the global variable directly in this way is nasty and goes against the whole DI movement etc)

I (think) I want to inject `windowProvider' into the config class, and get the variable from there. Something like this:

```
function AngularConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $windowProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    let partialsRoot = $windowProvider.$get().localized.partials;

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: partialsRoot + '/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .when('/projects/', {
            templateUrl: partialsRoot + '/projects.html',
            controller: 'ProjectsController'
        })
        .when('/contact/', {
            templateUrl: partialsRoot + '/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}

export default AngularConfig;
```

But I can't work out how to modify the `window`/`windowProvider` before the tests start the module.
I've tried this:

```
beforeEach(module(MODULE_NAME, function ($windowProvider) {
    let $window = $windowProvider.$get();
    $window.localized = {
        partials: 'some-path/'
    };
    console.log("WINDOW:", $window);
}));
```

However, the `console.log` does not get executed unless I don't reference `.localized.partials` in the config class - which makes me think the module (and the config) are being instantiated before the function to modify the `window`

Any help or pointers with this would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `$window` service is there is that it can be stubbed/mocked, so there's no need to tear down real `window` if services pollute it.

Original `$window` service refers to `window` any way, as well as `$windowProvider.$get()`, so they can be used interchangeably with `window`.

Since Angular services are singletons, the benefit of injecting `$window` service is that it can be mocked and used across the app and refer to the same mocked object. Normally `$window` can be mocked like this

```
// module order matters
module(($provide) => {
  $provide.factory('$window', () => {});
}, 'app');
```

This isn't true when Angular DI is abused with `$windowProvider.$get()`. When called like this it will refer to different object rather than mocked `$window`, this object cannot be reached from anywhere but function scope that called it.

This behaviour can be fixed by mocking `$window` like that:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  module({ $window: {} }, 'app');
  ...
```

This way

- `$windowProvider` is mocked before it is injected into app `config` block
- `$windowProvider.$get` and `$window` refer to the same `{}` object because the object was created on service definition and was't wrapped in factory function
- fresh `{}` object is reissued for each spec.

---

But the proper way to do this is to just use `constant`:

```
app.constant('localized', window.localized);
```

It is there exactly for that. To get rid of global constants through DI and use them during config and run phases. It can be mocked like any other service

```
module(($provide) => {
  $provide.constant('localized', {});
}, 'app');
```